# Ado.NET Entity Generator Error with German version

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, generator

When I add a 'ADO.NET code generation element' and choose 'ADO.NET self tracking entity generator' I get some errors. After some inspection on the templates I figured it out, that the German localization seems to corrupt them by using double quotations, where the English original has single quotations. Since double quotations are used as string-delimiter in C#, the templating process fails at the corresponding lines.
Afterwards I chased up the faulty string in the `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Resources.dll`.

My short solution was to delete that assembly and thus removing the German localization of the entity object generator.

This works anyway, but cannot be a solution, that is meant to be. Anyone encountered a similar problem or/and has another approach?

Comment: Another reason why to avoid any localized tools. IT guys should be able to use tools in English...